# Installing Ubuntu, screen does not follow from instruction

Tags: system-installation

I am following the instructions to install Ubuntu from https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

The screens on the computer look nothing like the instructions.
First off, I'm booting from a USB flash drive, the image I have is ubuntu-`16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`.

The download updates while installing Ubuntu cannot be checked, only the install third-party software for graphics can be checked. The instructions on the web page say we suggest you select both.

Instructions on next web page say I will see Allocate Drive Space, where I am to erase disk and install Ubuntu. Instead I see Install, Installation type, `/dev/sda`.

Why is my screen different than the instructions ?

I am stuck here on a step with no guidance from the instructions. If I click Install Now, the dialog says:

> No root file system is defined Please correct this from the
>   partitioning menu.

There is no Partitioning Menu, however there is a New Partition Table button ..., so I click that believing maybe that is what you mean. (Please be precise next time around.)  I get following dialog:

> You have selected an entire device to partiton. If you proceed with
>   creating a new partition table ... all current partitions will be
>   removed.

Now I have an extra line under `/dev/sda` with "free space", I click install now. I get:

> No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the
>   partitioning menu.

Again, there is no such thing as a partitioning menu. Why are the instructions wrong!

I played around with this a whole lot, and can't move forward by just intuit-ing the answer.

Please I'm stuck. And I haven't even began to install Ubuntu.

Comment: *What* do you see on your screen? Could you please post a picture, or at least a step by step exact transcript? As far as I know the tutorial is quite correct; at least I have never been confronted with significant deviations from the screen captures presented in the tutorial.

Comment: As Alex suggests, it would be helpful if you could take a pic of your screen and add it to your question, so we can understand what is different. Is your computer's internet connection working? If it is not, then the "Download updates" option is grayed out. Also, you need to select "Something else" in step 6 in order to see the partitioning menu.  Here is another site that shows some of these steps in more detail: https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-17-10-installation-guide-screenshots/

Comment: @Joe Molnar, there different views for the "Installation type" pages in the installer.  My guess is, you are not seeing the "basic" page because your disk does not currently have a partition table on it. **Is it a new disk?**  The instructions you linked to are *very* basic, intended for *most* users with a computer that already has an operating system. The link that I shared in my comment above shows more advanced screen shots that may apply to your scenario. Nevertheless, you are OK. You just need to create the partition table and create the partitions.

Comment: @Joe Molnar, When I get home this evening, I'll see if I can capture some screen shots to help you out, and I'll post them. It sounds like you are a little frustrated, but don't give up; Ubuntu/Linux are really great, but once in a while, we all have to get through some "learning curves."

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. The askubuntu.com page says I need 10 points to be able to upload images. Maybe it's best if I reach out to a guy to come to my house and help install. I'll update the post when I understand what he found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to download updates during installation because your Ethernet cable or wireless is not connected.  You can take care of this and get updates after you've installed Ubuntu.  For now, you can proceed with the installation without installing updates.

You may not be seeing the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option because of the way your disk is formatted or partitioned.  These instructions will help you partition your disk correctly.

**Note: These instructions assume you want to DELETE your ENTIRE disk.  All DATA on your disk will be LOST.  All existing operating systems on your disk will be lost.**

1. Launch the installer.

   Notice, I've disabled my network to simulate your situation.

   Click <kbd>Install Ubuntu</kbd>

   [image: Step 1]
2. Because the network is disabled, the option to "Download updates..." is not available.

   However, "Install third-party software..." is still available because the DVD already contains the necessary files. You can select this now, if you wish.

   Click <kbd>Continue</kbd>

   [image: Step 2]
3. At this point, you *sould* see the following screen.

   If you see this screen, select "Something else" option and click the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button.

   If you don't see this screen, that's OK; just move on to the next step.

   [image: Step 3]
4. On the next screen, you will see your disk.  It will be listed as "/dev/XXX".

   Select "/dev/XXX", and click the <kbd>New Partition Table...</kbd> button.

   [image: Step 4]
5. In the dialog that pops up, click the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button.

   [image: Step 5]
6. Now you will see your disk "/dev/XXX" again.

   There will be free space listed underneath it (if it wasnt there before).

   [image: Step 6]
7. Select "free space", and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button.

   [image: Step 7]
8. A "Create Partition" dialog will appear.

   - In the Size field, enter 256 MB.
   - For the "Type for the new partition:", select "Primary".
   - For the "Location of the new partition:", make sure "Beginning of this space" is selected.
   - For the "Use as:" drop-down, select "Ext4 journaling file system".
   - For the "Mount point:" drop down, select "/boot".
   - Click the <kbd>OK</kbd>.

   [image: Step 8]
9. Once again, select "free space", and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button.

   - The "Create Partition" dialog will reappear.
   - In the Size field, enter the size of memory in your system in MB. It doesn't have to be exact. (Since I have 4GB of memory, I've selected 4096).  If you're unsure what to use, 8192 MB would be a good number to enter here.
   - For the "Type for the new partition:", select "Primary".
   - For the "Location of the new partition:", make sure "Beginning of this space" is selected.
   - For the "Use as:" drop-down, select "swap area".
   - Click the <kbd>OK</kbd>.

   [image: Step 9]
10. Once again, select "free space", and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button.

    - The "Create Partition" dialog will reappear.
    - In the Size field, leave the default value that appears.
    - For the "Type for the new partition:", select "Primary".
    - For the "Location of the new partition:", make sure "Beginning of this space" is selected.
    - For the "Use as:" drop-down, select "Ext4 journaling file system".
    - For the "Mount point:" drop down, select "/".
    - Click the <kbd>OK</kbd>.

    [image: Step 10]
11. Finally, your screen should look something like this.

    Click the <kbd>Install Now</kbd> button.

    [image: Step 11]
12. A confirmation dialog will appear.

    Click the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button.

    [image: Step 12]
13. At last you will see the following screen.

    This is the same as step 8 in the Install Ubuntu instructions you have already been following, so you can continue the rest of the installation from there: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#7

    [image: Step 13]